# javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller vs org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm using the Unmarshaller with Spring Web Services. I see examples around the web and it looks like both of these interfaces are used interchangeably.  I'm wondering if one is better than the other?

What is the difference between both and why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically "generic interface" vs. "specific implementation".

`org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller` is a Spring interface which is stricter that `javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` but has different implemetations (not just JAXB).

`javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` is richer, but it's just JAXB.

If you're using Spring beans hen they'll mostly expect the Spring interface.

Comment: Thanks lexi. I ended up using the Spring interface, I found it was a bit more robust and could be configured easier.